# "is normally not meant to ..." or "in not normally meant to ..."?

Tags: adverb-placement

Where to put the adverb normally in the following sentence.

> 1. That **is not normally meant** to be offensive.

or

> 2. That **is normally not meant** to be offensive.

Comment: Both are acceptable, with the first being, in my opinion, the more common form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adverb "normally" can modify the past participle of the verb (meant) or it can modify another adverb (not), so it's acceptable to put it in either place. The meanings are mostly interchangeable here and will be understood in exactly the same way in most contexts.

There's possibly a very tiny difference in the nuance of the meaning. I would probably use the second one in a context like the following:

> I don't think that person meant to offend you, because that is normally not meant to be offensive.

I am emphasizing that it is normal for it to **not** mean whatever you took it to mean. In other words, the negation is what is normal.

On the other hand, I might be more likely to use the first one in a context like the following:

> Although that is not normally meant to be offensive, I think that person may have intended to offend you this time.

I am emphasizing a contrast between its normal meaning and what it may have meant this time. In other words, I'm negating its normal meaning.

Such differences are very minor, though, and either syntax will be understood in either context. To my ear, "not normally meant" sounds more common.

Comment: Pretty much applies to `usually` as well.